# How can I fill an array with all of the values between two numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to understand Arrays a bit more. I want to create a loop to fill an array with all the values between two numbers. However it seems that I can only get it to "reset" the value of a single location of the array. Everything else gets set back to zero. Below is my code:

```
public class ArrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int indexLow = 3;
    int length = 10;

    for(int i=indexLow; i<indexLow+length; i++){    
          int[] MyArray = new int[length+indexLow];
          MyArray[i] = i;
          System.out.println(MyArray[i]);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyArray));
          }
```

}
}

The output is not quite what I am expecting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're making a new array every iteration.

Comment: What you loop says is "_every time I go into the loop, make a brand new array with nothing in it. Add something. Print it. Repeat_"

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have meant to put int[] MyArray = new int[length+indexLow]; before your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've got what appears to be two problems.

As expertly pointed out in the other answers, you're creating your array anew every time through the iteration.  You need to move the declaration and instantiation of the array outside of the loop.

But now, you've got another slight issue.  If you have numbers from 3 to 10 exclusive, then you'd only have 7 numbers in your array.  That means that the size of your array is off by twice the value of what your `indexLow` value is.

That means basically, you'd change your array declaration statement to this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[length - indexLow];
```

...with the loop to follow.

As a bonus, if you were using Java 8, you could take advantage of `IntStream` and its `range` method to do the same thing:

```
int[] myArray = IntStream.range(indexLow, length).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
for(int i=indexLow; i<indexLow+length; i++){    
   int[] myArray = new int[length+indexLow];
   myArray[i] = i;
}
```

Which creates a new array on each loop iteration. It needs to be

```
int[] myArray = new int[length+indexLow];
for(int i=indexLow; i<indexLow+length; i++){    
   myArray[i] = i;
}
```

So you create the array once, and populate each element during the loop.